# PHP form escapes html field after submit

Tags: php, html, apache

I have the following problem.

I am using a form to submit a textarea which includes HTML tags.

```
<div style="width:100%;display:block;float:left;">
   <p>Name: <strong>test</strong><br />
   Address: <strong>address</strong><br />
   Date:<strong> 09/12/2014</strong></p>
</div>
```

However, when I submit the form via POST I get the following result:

```
   div style=width:100;display:block;float:left; pName: strongΓΕΩΡΓΙΑ ΙΩΑΝΝΗΣ ΓΕΩΡΓΙΑΔΗ/strongbr / Address: strongΟΔΟΣ ΠΕΝΤΕΛΗΣ 110 , 15231 ΜΑΡΟΥΣΙ, Greece/strongbr / Date:strong 09/12/2014/strong/p /div
```

PHP magic quotes are **off**

When I was trying that on my development machine it was working fine, but now that I moved it to a dedicated server is not working as it should.

Can you please help?

Comment: What does it mean, you get that result. You want a prefilled textarea, where user needs to update its credentials?

Comment: This is not working. It returns the same result as the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

Use `htmlspecialchars($_POST['html'], ENT_QUOTES)` and when you echo it again (from database) use `htmlspecialchars_decode($result['html'])`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

If i use:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['send'])){
    $html = htmlspecialchars($_POST['html']);
    echo $html;
    echo htmlspecialchars_decode($html);
}
?>
<form method="POST">
    <textarea name="html">

    </textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send" />
</form>
```

It works, so maybe it's something with your database?

Comment: This is not working. It returns the same result as the problem.

Comment: @curiusX it works when i post the form in my answer (see updated answer above). So maybe it's your database that causes the problems? You do escape the post value?

Comment: Yeap. I finally found out that a content filter was running which was loaded from the .htaccess file. However, i have tested your answer in another server and it is working and as a result i will accept the answer.